# Strange behavior in ngTable when appending a row

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ev3eyTd5W0v38URWH7m9?p=preview) I tried to replicate my problem, but I couldn't so it's the best approximation.

If you click on the button, you will add a row to the table. Also, the row background will change color and fade after two seconds. Since the maximum number of rows in the table is three, when adding the fourth row ngTable will add a page. If you go to the next page, and then back, in my environment **you see the fourth row in the first page for two seconds, and then it disappears.**

Another similar symptom happens when I sort a column by clicking on its header, I also get the additional row for two seconds and then it disappears.

Again, this works fine in Plunker but not in my environment. **If I disable the effect in my environment, ngTable works fine.**

Is there a conflict with the effect? **is there a different way to do the effect?**

HTML

```
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="u in $data" 
                ng-class="{true: 'select-row', false: 'unselect-row'}[u.select]">
                <td title="'ID'">
                    {{ u.uid }}
                </td>
                <td title="'Name'">
                  {{ u.nm }}
                </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br/>
    <button ng-click="appendRow()">Append row</button>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$timeout,NgTableParams) {

      $scope.data = [{
          uid: 1,
          nm: 'aaa'
      }, {
          uid: 2,
          nm: 'bbb'
      }];

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
          count: 3
      }, {
          dataset: $scope.data
      });


      $scope.appendRow = function(){
        var len = $scope.data.length;
        $scope.data.push({ uid: len + 1, nm: 'XXXXX' });
        selectRow(len);
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
      };


     var selectRow = function(row){
        $scope.data[row].select = true;
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.data[row].select = false;
        },2000);
    };

});
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I found: since the value of `$scope.data[row].select` is false, whenever there's a pagination, ngTable picks up the effect, even though `$scope.data[row].select` was not set with `true` beforehand. This class transition is triggered needlessly, and makes ngTable show an additional row for the transition time, then it dissapears:

```
.unselect-row {
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 1.2s linear all; 
}
```

Comment: why is it `ng-repeat="u in $data"` and not `ng-repeat="u in data"` ?

Comment: It's the way I took it from the examples. I tried both ways and I still have the problem.

Comment: How is the code on the plunker different from what is in your environment?  You have given working code here, and shown that it works perfectly in plunker.  The code works perfectly fine in a private environment for me as well, which means this is something specific to your environment, or other code in your app that you aren't showing here.   It would be very hard for anyone to tell you what is going on without being able to see the issue, save for a wild guess.

Comment: I know, it's the best I can do. I posted the question as is to see if anyone else had a similar problem or any ideas how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the object member that triggered the animation solved the problem, ngTable otherwise was triggering the animation needlessly on pagination:

```
        $scope.data[row].select = false;
        $timeout(function(){
            delete $scope.data[row].select;
        },1000);
```